# How to retrieve subarray elements in JSON with Javascript with out JSON Heder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to string these type JSON

```
[
  '6.8533636387161,79.89397289528804',
  '6.841479977297953,79.93689064345428',
  '6.794774598377703,79.8924977647096',
  '6.9220240337166,80.18059740336115',
  '6.928709723114853,79.90020056130511',
  '6.779762567644507,79.97220252562504',
  '6.889343988321676,79.91672708572148',
  '6.817046093931518,79.96475696868056',
  '6.854384537575061,80.08285194187849',
  '6.796609462165447,79.90870482526962'
]
```

Comment: You don't have sub-array elements. The elements of this array are strings, not arrays.

Comment: I want to print

lat:6.916528204683724,lon:80.20218123746356

each one by one

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: Use the `split()` function to split a string at the comma delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply using `map` and `split`. First, map through the array and then split every element by comma (,) and return a new array of objects.

```js
const data = [
  '6.8533636387161,79.89397289528804',
  '6.841479977297953,79.93689064345428',
  '6.794774598377703,79.8924977647096',
  '6.9220240337166,80.18059740336115',
  '6.928709723114853,79.90020056130511',
  '6.779762567644507,79.97220252562504',
  '6.889343988321676,79.91672708572148',
  '6.817046093931518,79.96475696868056',
  '6.854384537575061,80.08285194187849',
  '6.796609462165447,79.90870482526962'
];

const res = data.map(value => {
    const [lat, lon] = value.split(',');
    return {lat, lon};
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: What would be the output format you want? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You could add brackets and parse the items as JSON and get the values.

```js
var array = ['6.8533636387161,79.89397289528804', '6.841479977297953,79.93689064345428', '6.794774598377703,79.8924977647096', '6.9220240337166,80.18059740336115', '6.928709723114853,79.90020056130511', '6.779762567644507,79.97220252562504', '6.889343988321676,79.91672708572148', '6.817046093931518,79.96475696868056', '6.854384537575061,80.08285194187849', '6.796609462165447,79.90870482526962'],
    result = array.map(s => {
        let [lat, lon] = JSON.parse(`[${s}]`);
        return { lat, lon };
    });

console.log(result);
```